# What is the difference between std::function and std::mem_fn

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, function-pointers, std-function

I am having trouble figuring out the difference between the two function wrappers [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn). From the description, it seems to me that std::function does everything `std::mem_fn` does and more. In which instance would one use `std::mem_fn` over `std::function`?

Comment: Do you mean `std::function` vs. the return type of `std::mem_fn`? Comparing a class template with a function template doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't really compare `std::function` with `std::mem_fn`. The former is a class template whose type you specify, and the latter is a function template with unspecified return type. There really isn't a situation in which you'd actually consider one versus the other.

A better comparison might be between `mem_fn` and `std::bind`. There, for the specific use-case of a pointer-to-member, `mem_fn` is going to a lot less verbose if all you want to do is pass-through all the arguments. Given this simple type:

```
struct A { 
    int x;
    int getX() { return x; }
    int add(int y) { return x+y; }
};

A a{2};
```

How would you make a functor that just calls `getX()` on a given `A`?

```
auto get1 = std::mem_fn(&A::getX);
auto get2 = std::bind(&A::getX, _1);

get1(a); // yields 2
get2(a); // same
```

And takes an additional argument for `add`?

```
auto add1 = std::mem_fn(&A::add);
auto add2 = std::bind(&A::add, _1, _2);

add1(a, 5); // yields 7
add2(a, 5); // same
```

So `mem_fn` is more concise *in this case*. However, if we wanted to bind a specific argument, say call `add(5)` on a given `A`, you can only do that with `bind`:

```
auto add_5 = std::bind(&A::add, _1, 5);
add_5(a); // yields 7
```

Ultimately, no comparison between `function` and `mem_fn`, but there are times to prefer `mem_fn` to `bind`.

Answer (score 12):

The wrapper returned by `std::mem_fn` is extremely lightweight; it's a thin wrapper around a pointer to member.

`std::function` uses type erasure, which is a lot more heavyweight.